# EAR Deployment Issues - Weblogic 10.3.6 - EntityManagerFactory not visible from class loader

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, weblogic

I'm upgrading a web-app that is hosted on 32-bit Weblogic 9.2 into 64-bit Weblogic 10.3.6. For this purpose, I have installed 64-bit Weblogic 10.3.6 on my Windows 7 PC and use OEPE 11.1.1.8 that I separately installed to test local builds and deploys.

Using Eclipse (ver. Indigo), when I publish the app into the local instance of 10.3.6 as a virtual-application, the app works as expected. However, when I change the mode to "exploded archive" I start getting all sorts of errors which, from what I've read so far, are due to [Weblogic Classloading](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/classloading.htm).

Example errors:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode

I fixed this by adding

```
<package-name>javax.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.*</package-name>
```

to the `weblogic-application.xml` file after which I've started seeing the following error which I haven't been able to fix:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface
>   javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory is not visible from class
>   loader

I've done the following so far:

In Eclipse, searched (using find-type) for the jar(s) that included this class and found a total of 3. Two - "`javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar`" and "`javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar`" - were under the Weblogic server installation ("`%BEA_HOME%\modules`") folder and 1 from the application lib path ("`WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`").

Given that the `javax.*` class filter is already in place (above), what else could I do to fix this issue?

If Weblogic doesn't like what I'm doing, why is it allowing the application to work when deployed as a virtual application?

Comment: I assume you mean `prefer-application-packages` rather then `package-name` 3 times? Maybe you need to choose your package at another depth like `javax.persistence.*` Have you analyzed the exploded archive vs. an ear/war file that works?